# Adding a loop to get result 'n' times and get the average into a csv - Python

Tags: python, loops, csv, particle-filter

I wrote a python function for particle filtering. I need to write a loop for the below function to save the best cost(Variable) for a csv file and get the average.

```
#loop should start here        
    pop_size=50
    #128 to #135 loop
    W = initial_population(region, scale , pop_size)

    pop = PatternPosePopulation(W, pat)
    pop.set_distance_image(imd)

    pop.temperature = 5

    Lw, Lc = pop.particle_filter_search(int(1000/pop_size),log=True)
    #Loop should end here for example run pop 50 x n times and store best_cost, take average of bestcost save to csv file.

    plt.plot(Lc)
    plt.title('Cost vs generation index')
    plt.show()

    print(pop.best_w)
    print(pop.best_cost)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is "n" in "50 x n times"? If there is no dependency of the step number, you can use `for i in range(50*n):`

Comment: @Alperen It could be any number. In my case it's '5'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
best_costs = []
for iteration in range(n):     
    pop_size=50
    W = initial_population(region, scale , pop_size)

    pop = PatternPosePopulation(W, pat)
    pop.set_distance_image(imd)

    pop.temperature = 5

    Lw, Lc = pop.particle_filter_search(int(1000/pop_size),log=True)

    best_costs.append(pop.best_cost)#store the best cost for this iteration

    #Loop should end here for example run pop 50 x n times and store best_cost, take average of bestcost save to csv file.

    plt.plot(Lc)
    plt.title('Cost vs generation index')
    plt.show()

    print(pop.best_w)
    print(pop.best_cost)

#write to csv
best_cost_total = min(best_costs)
best_cost_avg = sum(best_costs) / n

results = [str(best_cost_total), str(best_cost_avg)]

with open('results.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(";".join(results))
```

This will write the best cost and the average to `results.csv` with `;` as delimiter. For a more specific approach, more information would be needed...

Edit: You're right, the writing to csv part should be after the loop

Comment: The error is probably caused by that weird 4-space indentation that stackoverflow uses. Just check if all indentations are actual tabs instead of spaces. Glad I could help

Comment: Sure I will do that. Now the indentation issue is alright. There's a value error "min() arg is an empty sequence". Any tip @LcdDrm ?

Comment: Lines 128 to 143 have to be inside the for loop, so you have to indent them